# Как удалить из строки все символы, кроме цифр и дефиса?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое условие в `regexp` мне нужно прописать, чтобы отсекались все символы, кроме цифр и дефиса?

Answer (score 3):

Может вот так?

```
.replace(/[^-0-9]/gi, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/^\D+|[^\d-]+|-(?=\D+)|\D+$/gim, '')
```

Если вам нужно что бы было типа формата дата например (gfgfd-11-04-2017-fdssdfs)
тогда нужно использовать вот такое выражение /^\D+|[^\d-]+|-(?=\D+)|\D+$/gim
на выходе (11-04-2017)
это конечно **не самый лучший вариант** выражения, но оно удаляет дефисы в начале и в конце
если использовать такое выражение [^\d-], то у Вас в конце и в начале
остаются дефисы (gfgfd-11-04-2017-fdssdfs)
на выходе (-11-04-2017-)